# Stored procedure to re-order rows in a table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got 2 tables [Pubs] and [Authors].  The [Pubs} can have many [Authors] and [Authors] can author many [Pubs] so I created a junction table [Pub_Authors] to deal with the many-to-many relationship.

Each author is given a priority on the pub and, from time to time, the leading author or publication manager will reassign authors a new priority on a whim.

```
TABLE STRUCTURE:
PA_ID INT
PUB_ID INT
AUTH_ID INT
PA_PRIORITY INT
OLD_PRI (I added this based on a possible solution found here)
```

The PROBLEM:
When the primary author reassigns a priority, I need to renumber the remaining authors' priorities from that point on and for that pub.

```
PA_ID   PUB_ID  AUTH_ID PA_PRIORITY  O_PRI
1       11      10      1            1
2       11      20      2            2
3       11      30      3            3
```

The example above shows data for ONE pub with 3 authors.
The publication manager changes the priority for AUTHOR 20 from 2 to 3.

What SHOULD happen:

```
PA_ID   PUB_ID  AUTH_ID PA_PRIORITY  O_PRI
1       11      10      1            1
2       11      20      3            2
3       11      30      2            3
```

Here's the SP I found in another example but it doesn't do quite what I'm looking for... It changes all of the priorities to a "3" instead of reordering them.

```
ALTER  Proc update_Publication_Author_Priority_Order (@ID Int, @NewPosition Int = 1)
As

Declare @OldPosition Int,
    @Direction Int

Select  @OldPosition = PA_PRIORITY 
From    Pub_Authors
Where   PUB_ID = @ID

Set     @Direction =    Case 
                    When    @OldPosition < @NewPosition Then 0
                    When    @OldPosition > @NewPosition Then 1
                    Else    -1
                    End

Update  t
Set     oldPri = PA_PRIORITY ,
    PA_PRIORITY =  Case
                When    PUB_ID = @ID Then @NewPosition
                When    @Direction = 0 And 
                        PA_PRIORITY Between @OldPosition And @NewPosition Then PA_PRIORITY - 1
                When    @Direction = 1 And 
                        PA_PRIORITY Between @NewPosition And @OldPosition Then PA_PRIORITY + 1
                Else    PA_PRIORITY 
                End
From    Pub_Authors t
```

I'm certain there is a simple fix, something I'm overlooking...  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Bob

Ok... after serious consideration, trial and error, this is what I have come up with as a possible solution.  My problem now is the multiple instructions during a CASE statement...

```
Update  t
Set     oldPri = PA_Priority,
    PA_Priority =  Case  -- add a counter and increment within the loop.
                When    PA_Priority < @NewPosition Then PA_Priority
                        @Counter + 1
                When    PA_Priority = @NewPosition Then @Counter
                        @Counter + 1
                When    PA_Priority > @NewPosition Then @Counter
                        @Counter + 1
                Else    PA_Priority
                                                         @Counter + 1
                End
```

From    Pub_Authors t
Where   PUB_ID IN (Select publicationID
                            From Pub_Authors
                            Where Pub_ID = @ID)

Comment: `Where   PUB_ID = @ID` should be `Where  PA_ID = @ID` I presume, that does not uniquely identify a row and it is non deterministic what `@OldPosition` will be assigned. Or include `AUTH_ID` assuming this is a composite unique index.

Comment: Using ROW_NUMBER would be a good way to renumber things like this. We can help if you can post ddl and sample data for the table(s) involved.

Comment: Do you have restrictions in place to prevent ad-hoc updates to the table?   Is it only possible to update the table one row at a time through your stored procedure?

Comment: @MartinSmith, doing this only updates records where the PA_ID (the record identifier for the junction table) is equal to the ID specified on execution.  What needs to happen is, all records for a given [PUB] need to be updated.

Comment: @SeanLange, sample data and the entire SP is posted.

Comment: @RLoomas - No, the `Select  @OldPosition = PA_PRIORITY From Pub_Authors` needs to have a unique where clause identifying the specific row whose priority is being changed. That where for all records for a given [PUB]  needs to be on the update.

Comment: @TabAlleman, I am sysAdmin on this server and have no restrictions on ad-hoc updates to the table... suggest away...

Comment: I'm not asking about YOUR restrictions, I'm asking about restrictions on your users.  What's to stop a user from running an UPDATE that will change the priorities of 20 different authors at once?   And if nothing is to stop them, then what do you want to have happen when they do that?

Comment: @TabAlleman, sorry, I misunderstood.  No, there are no restrictions on how many can be changed at a given time.  As to what I want to happen, it can update in either of 2 ways... 1) as soon as the priority is changed, call the SP... 2) have the SP assigned to a button that the user would click and run the SP to reorder the group.  The first is preferred because the user can see the result right away and (for my users) clicking an extra button is a burden they don't want.  Also, there are not typically 20 authors on a given publication... usually about 5.

Comment: Yes but if users can do adhoc updates, they won't be limited to updating the author's priority on a single publication.   They could join to the author's table, and set the priority to "1" for every author whose name starts with "T".   If users can do adhoc updates, the only way to meet your requirement is with a Trigger.

Comment: @TabAlleman, no... they are restricted to accessing ONLY those publications with which they are associated and have permission to modify.  This limitation is in the C# code behind and they cannot even view a publication with which they are not assigned.  And, the form on which they will do the update only allows them to update one author at a time.  But, good point.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to correct what you you have already would be to fix a few places.

```
Select  @OldPosition = PA_PRIORITY 
From    Pub_Authors
Where   PUB_ID = @ID
```

should probably be

```
Select  @OldPosition = PA_PRIORITY 
From    Pub_Authors
Where   PA_ID = @ID
```

then your update WHERE needs to change to get the correct pub_ids and the first CASE needs to look at PA_ID

```
UPDATE  t
SET     oldPri = PA_PRIORITY,
        PA_PRIORITY = CASE WHEN PA_ID = @ID THEN @NewPosition
                           WHEN @Direction = 0
                                AND PA_PRIORITY BETWEEN @OldPosition AND @NewPosition THEN PA_PRIORITY - 1
                           WHEN @Direction = 1
                                AND PA_PRIORITY BETWEEN @NewPosition AND @OldPosition THEN PA_PRIORITY + 1
                           ELSE PA_PRIORITY
                      END
FROM    Pub_Authors t
WHERE   PUB_ID IN (SELECT   PUB_ID
                   FROM     Pub_Authors
                   WHERE    PA_ID = @ID)
```

You can also do this using ROW_NUMBER.  I've tested this a few times and it seems to work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_Publication_Author_Priority_Order (
     @ID INT,
     @NewPosition INT = 1
    )
AS 
    BEGIN
        WITH cte AS
        (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN PA_ID = @ID THEN @NewPosition ELSE [PA_PRIORITY] END, [PA_PRIORITY] DESC) Rn 
            FROM    Pub_Authors
            WHERE   PUB_ID IN (SELECT PUB_ID FROM Pub_Authors WHERE PA_ID = @ID)
        )      
        UPDATE cte SET [PA_PRIORITY] = Rn, [O_PRI] = [PA_PRIORITY];

    END
GO
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34004/2)

Comment: That changes all of the priorities for all of the publications for which that author is attributable.

Comment: @RLoomas I actually edited the answer to look at PA_ID instead.. you might need to refresh

Comment: Thanks, but that change was already incorporated... but, now I have another idea to try...

Comment: @ JamieD77, I changed that on your suggestion.  The new idea is to increment a counter but I don't know where I would do that in the PA_PRIORITY = CASE ...

Comment: @RLoomas  not sure what you mean by counter but i added a suggestion using ROW_NUMBER that might work for you

Comment: I updated the question with what I'm trying to do with a counter.  I tried the ROW_NUMBER idea and it seems to return the row number of the record in the table (rown number 500 of 10,000) not in the results (row 5 of 10).

Answer (score 0):

So basically your question is how to keep an updatable order column in a table. The easiest way to do it is to keep the oreder in a numeric column instead of an int column, that way you can set any record to any place without updating any other row in the talbe. Say you want to move the fourth record to the second place. All you have to do is update it's number to 1.5.